# Random variables and rel valued functions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have a question regarding a definition I found in the book "Introduction to Stochastic Processes" by Erhan Cinlar:

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in a set $E$, and let $f$ be a real valued function defined on the set $E$. Then for each $\omega \in \Omega, X(\omega)$ is a point in $E$ and $f$ assigns the value $f(X(\omega))$ to that point. By $f(X)$ we mean the random variable whose value at $\omega \in \Omega$ is $f(X(\omega))$. A particular function of some use is the indicator function $I_B$ of a subset $B$ of $E ; I_B(x)$ is 1 or 0 according as $x \in B$ or $x \notin B$. Then $I_B(X)$ is a random variable which is equal to 1 if the event $\{X \in B\}$ occurs and is equal to 0 otherwise. Quite often there will be a number of random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and we will be concerned with functions of them. If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ take values in $E$, and if $f$ is a real valued function $f$ defined on $E \times \cdots \times E=E^n$, then $f\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right)$ is a real-valued random variable whose value at $\omega \in \Omega$ is $f\left(X_1(\omega), \ldots, X_n(\omega)\right)$.

I cannot figure out how the definition of random variable as a "map between sample space and the real line" fits into this definition I provided you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition do you use exactly? In the example of the indicator function can you tell us, what space your sample space is and whether $I_B(X)$ has the real line as a co-domain?

Comment: Suppose I use a general definition as: "a random variable $X$ with values in $E$ is a function which assigns a value $X(w)$ in $E$ to each outcome e in $\Omega$". Is the one I provided in the question simply a definition of a function of a random variable? What is confusing me is the phrase "By $f(X)$ we mean the random variable whose value at $\omega \in \Omega$ is $f(X(\omega))$."

Comment: What exactly do you find confusing about this, for you does it satiesfy the definition of a random variable, if not why?

Answer (score 0):

A random variable is a measurable function $X: \Omega \to E$ from a sample space  to a measurable set $E$.

Hence it is simply a function that, given a $\omega \in \Omega$, assigns a value $X(\omega)$ in $E$. If you name your function $f$, then the value in $E$ you obtain is $f(\omega)$.

In your example you have a composition of the rv $X:\Omega \to E$ and a function $f: E \to E'$ which yields a function $g: \Omega \to E'$ which is a new rv that to the point $\omega$ assigns the value $f(X(\omega))$.